# White space on right of page - mysterious

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do I get rid of this white space on the side of my website? I am out of ideas, and I cannot seem to see what the problem is that is causing every page of my website to have this white space.

Can somebody help and look at this in firebug? - see if there is something I have missed..
The website is here:
[www.sugarskull.co](http://www.sugarskull.co)

[image]

Comment: It's not there for me using Firefox 37.0.2 for Ubuntu.

Comment: everything look fine on my browser.. may be a plugin cause this. can you disable your browser plugins and try

Comment: hmmm... Mac OSX 10.10.3 Firefox 37.0.2 with all add ons disabled - problem still there! :l Only appears when the user scrolls right. (added an image)

Comment: I confirm, it's not visible right away tho. I have a horizontal scrollbar, and only when I scroll to the right I see this gap.

Comment: Try adding width to both your menu and content divs

Comment: So remove the scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on chrome and I noticed on your `<div>` `top-pusher` that you have a height of 45px.

Removing this

```
#top-pusher {
  /* height: 45px; */
}
```

removes the side line that you are talking about, I also did not notice a change in layout (for fullscreen after removal.

When in mobile, you have padding around your header, which is why the black menu button doesn't touch the window:

```
body#home div#header {
  background: transparent;
}
```

just add `padding:0` to the `div#header` and that should remove the padding margin on the menu/nav bar.

Edit:
The space bar seems to only be on the homepage, so you should be targeting just that page with this fix:

```
#home #top-pusher{
/* fixes right side gape */
height:0px;
}

#home div.sequence-theme{
/* removes white space on bottom */
margin:0;
}

@media /*Your mobile screen size */
    body#home div#header {
      background: transparent;
/*removes spacing allow your nav bar to touch the sides of the window*/
padding:0;
    }
```

Comment: You are right - removing the top pusher corrected the issue. However, I need this height to push the main content down to not hide the breadcrumbs. I know, not great architecture but it was my quick solution. I have since just added a `width:100%` which corrects the issue.

Comment: Ah I see, that's my fault, if you only need the white space corrected on the homepage, you can target it based off a body class. `.home #top-pusher`.

Comment: now there is a white space on the bottom when you scroll now!! >:(

Comment: add `margin:0` onto  `div.sequence-theme` to remove the bottom white bar.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following css to `#top-pusher`  `margin-right:0;margin-left:0;`

you may also need to add !important as you are grabbing styles from `.row`